# Show only interior of the cube?

Tags: normals

Is it possible to show only interior of the cube in normal mode?

I made flip normals, but still see convex shape

Comment: The question isn't clear, attach images to explain the question better, what do you mean by convex shape? What render engine are you using? And what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35898/cant-render-an-inside-out-cube/35906#35906